# C# code : count total no of digits, alphabets and special characters in mettl platform

Tags: c#, count, return, user-input, digits

How to write a code to count total no of digits, alphabets and special characters in mettl platform

how to return the output in above code

how to use return statement in below code

```
public string countstring(string input1)
{
    int digits, alphabet, specialcharacters, i = 0;
    int L = input1.Lenght;
    for(i = 0;i <= L; i++)
    {
        if((input1[i] >= 'a' && input1[i] <= 'z') || (input1[i] >= 'A' && input1[i] <= 'Z'))            
        {               
            alphabet++;           
        }            
        else if (input1[i] >= '0' && input1[i] <= '9')           
        {                 
            digits++;           
        }             
        else            
        {                
            specialcharacters++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: C# supports only a single value as return. See [csharp-return-statement-with-examples](https://www.tutlane.com/tutorial/csharp/csharp-return-statement-with-examples). so you can use "out" parameters or you need to generate an object / class / tuple to return more then a single value.

Comment: You want the return value as string? How should this string look like? Something like "2 alpha, 4 digits, 0 special"?

Comment: return value as int
like example input1 = Klaus12, it should return 5,2,0

Answer (score 1):

You have to return multiple values using a tuple

```
public static (int, int, int) count(string input) {
    int digits = 0;
    int alphabet = 0;
    int special = 0;

    foreach (var c in input) {
        if (char.IsDigit(c)) {
            digits++;
        }
        else if (char.IsLetter(c)) {
            alphabet++;
        }
        else {
            special++;
        }
    }
    return (digits, alphabet, special);
}
```

Comment: `char.IsLetter` might be more appropriate than `char.IsAscii`

Comment: public string countstring(string input1)
this  statement cant be edited in code

Comment: What do you mean by can't be edited in code?